# If $z_n \rightarrow 0$, and if $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, then $\{c_n z_n\} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is my progress:

For complex sequences $\{s_n\}, \{t_n\}$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s,\  \lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t$, it follows that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} cs_n = cs \text{ for any number } c$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n t_n= st$$
Since $\{ c_n \}$ is bounded, it follows that $c < \{ c_n \} < c'$ for some arbitrary values $c, c'$.

$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} c_n z_n= c \cdot 0 = \limsup_{n \to \infty} c_n z_n= c' \cdot 0 = 0 $$

Hence, $\{ c_n z_n \} \rightarrow 0$.

I do not think this would qualify as a mathematically rigorous statement, and thus, as a proof :(

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In fact it *almost* does....if you rearrange it in the correct way. Using your symbols: $$cz_n\le c_nz_n\le cz_n$$ and now just apply the squeeze theorem. Or directly: $$0\le |c_nz_n|\le M|z_n|$$ and again the squeeze theorem, with $\;M\;$ a bound for $\;\{c_n\}\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, there exist $c\in \Bbb R$ (the word 'arbitrary' is not completely right) such that for all $n\in \Bbb N$

$$0\leq |c_n|<c\ \ .$$

Thus, if we multiply by $|z_n|$, we get

$$0\leq |z_n||c_n|<c|z_n|\ \ .$$

Can you figure out what to do now? (some kind of 'squeeze theorem' would be useful).

Comment: I added some extra work that I thought was kinda embarassing, would you mind looking over it?

Comment: Well, the use of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ here is completely innecesary, and it's not completely right (in general, it's not true that the limit inferior of two sequences equals the product of the inferior limits, see this link: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/lim-inf-and-product-commutation.235990/ )

Answer (score 1):

Let $|c_n| \leq B$ be the bound for $|c_n|$.

For all $\varepsilon >0$ eventually you have
$$|c_nz_n| = |c_n||z_n| \leq B \cdot \varepsilon / B = \varepsilon $$
when you take $n$ large enough to have $|z_n| \leq \varepsilon / B$.